# Cake php migration from 1.3 to 2.0 , cake upgrade all command not working

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

Hi i follow the migrion guide for cakephp 2.0  from thier site in order to update  my site framework from 1.3 to 2.0 , but the command

> cake upgrade all

doing nothhing . it dont change the name of any files when i run the command i get the following out put

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : Console
Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Running tests
Running locations
Running i18n
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running helpers
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running basics
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running request
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running configure
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running constants
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
Running components
Done updating C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\cake.php
```

**NOTE** Also when i open cake console i get this out put

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.0.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : Console
Path: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:

-app: Console
-working: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app\Console
-root: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\app
-core: C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-2.0.0\lib

Changing Paths:

Your working path should be the same as your application path to change your pat
h use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp
```

Is it be working path issue  or i am missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508973/typing-the-command-cake-in-console-shows-no-output/23510204#23510204 You are in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mark for pointing me in right direction , for future readers

The issue i was in  wrong folder . and i was running command like **cd Console/cake** **(the worng way)**

### RIGHT WAY

Fow linux or mac  users after opening your app folder in CMD run the command.

```
./Console/cake upgrade all
```

Fow windows users   after opening your app folder in CMD run the command.

```
 .\Console\cake upgrade all
```